Colour body of flextable
I am piping data into the following in the hope to put a blue table around my data where am I going wrong?
 |> 
 flextable::flextable() |> 
 colors(color = 'blue',part = "body")
 

I get the following error

Error in colors(flextable::flextable(filter(select(EPR, region, organisation),  : unused arguments (colors = "blue", part = "body")


It is a typo, try color(color = 'blue',part = "body")

"blue table around my data" - not clear, do you want a blue lines around table, or fill the background or text colour?

lines around the table

Either use flextable::bg() instead of colors(), and replace argument color with bg (~background) to change the background colour,
library(flextable)
head(datasets::CO2) |>
  flextable() |>
  bg(bg = 'blue', part = "body")


or do
library(flextable)
head(datasets::CO2) |>
  flextable() |>
  color(color = 'blue', part = "body")

to change the text colour of the body's text.


flextable::color() vs grDevices::colors()
